# Cannot set/find truststore after being set in setenv.sh - "trustStore is: No File Available"

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, truststore

I'm using a Tomcat server to host a Spring application and need to add the truststore directly into the JVM.

I modified my `setenv.sh` to have :

```
CATALINA_OPTS=$CATALINA_OPTS" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/home/osadmin/trustore"
CATALINA_OPTS=$CATALINA_OPTS" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit"
```

But ended up with the following error each time I tried to connect to the AD I need to connect to.

```
Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

My truststore was created in `KeyStore Explorer` and I imported each public certificate I needed. It was then downloaded on the server and the right all set to `a+wrx` to test.

The full debug with command `debug=all` + `grep -i truststore` showed the following lines

```
 cat /opt/application/XXXXX/XXXXX/tomcat/00/logs/catalina.out | grep -i truststore
03-Jun-2020 18:20:42.431 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/home/osadmin/trustore
03-Jun-2020 18:20:42.431 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
trustStore is: No File Available, using empty keystore.
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is :
init truststore
trustStore is: No File Available, using empty keystore.
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is :
```

Yet it exists :

[image: Yet it exists]

How can I set the truststore correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a very simple matter of rights.

+w on above folders so they can navigate through them.